# Extraction of raw date entites from the PDF in python

Tags: python, regex, date, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Firstly, I need to extract the text from the pdf. So, I used fitz to extract the text. After that for the date extraction from that text.

I used regex pattern -
`'(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})|(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{2,4})|(?:[\s]?\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]*)?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,./]*(?:\d{1,2}[-/th|st|nd|rd)\s,]*)?(?:\d{2,4})'`

but It is not extracting properly. false positive rate is more.

Some format like `02-05-1898` is extracting. but, another date of same format is not extracting.

Is there any problem while extracting text from the pdf?

Comment: `[-/th|st|nd|rd\s]` is totally wrong, you need to use grouping rather than character class for alternatives.

Comment: Which date formats should your pattern cover? Could you provide an exhaustive list of formats you would like to address?

Comment: The regex you have refactors into this `(?:\d{1,2}(?:/\d{1,2}/|-\d{1,2}-)|(?:[\s]?\d{1,2}[dhnr-t\s\-/|]*)?(?:J(?:an|u[ln])|Feb|Ma[ry]|A(?:pr|ug)|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)?[a-z\s,./]*(?:\d{1,2}[dhnr-t\s),\-/|]*)?)\d{2,4}` Check if this is your intended one.